# Parsing XML with JDOM

Tags: java, jdom

I want to use JDOM, so I want to Know the equivalent to this code written by DOM:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
URL Url = new URL(url);
Document doc = builder.parse(Url.openStream());
```

I use this example:

```
//On crée une instance de SAXBuilder
 SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
 try
 {
     //On crée un nouveau document JDOM avec en argument le fichier XML
     //Le parsing est terminé ;)
     document = sxb.build(new File("Exercice2.xml"));
  }
  catch(Exception e){}
```

but I want to use an URL instead of an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

So pass the `URL` to the `SAXBuilder.build` method. It's [right there in the Javadoc](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.html#build%28java.net.URL%29).